Input number does not respect step
the input is always showing 4 decimal places.  Is there a way to limit it to 2?
I've tried doing a math.round at the database, I've tried using formatting of f2, it does not seem that anything I try will get the thing to limit to 2 decimal places.
@page "/"
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
<input type="number"
       step="0.01"
       class="rounded no-spinner p-2 text-right w-full"
       @bind="currentCount" />

@functions {
    decimal currentCount = 0.0001m;

    void IncrementCount()
    {
            currentCount = currentCount + 1.2m;
    }
}

blazorfiddle

I'm not used to blazor yet, but I'm sure you can declare the currentCount with get set operators, you can format the output with it

I think the step number is only applicable when you click the up and down button in the input file. Now you are setting the variable value from code behind which is not applicable to the input file. Probably you need to "format" the value to 2 decimal places during assigning value to the variable.

I tried the format like:

and it did not help

The get/set operators won't change the underlying values.  The "real" implementation of this is that it's coming from the database and binding to an object with the same "decimal" type.  The fiddle is just a minimum recreation, so the suggestion for getters and setters is kind of already in place.

@GiovanniPerillo  Actually, this works.  I find it strange because I previously tried doing the math.round at the database fetch and it had no effect, but adding it on the object's property did.  Submit it as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thank you!

As I commented before, I suggest the use of get setters.
My suggested code is as follows:
private decimal currentCount = 0.0001m;

public decimal CurrentCount
{
    get => Math.Round(currentCount, 2);
    set => currentCount = value;
}

And as for the bind you can simply declare the new value @bind="CurrentCount"
@page "/"
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @CurrentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
<input type="number"
       step="0.01"
       class="rounded no-spinner p-2 text-right w-full"
       @bind="CurrentCount" />

@functions {
    decimal currentCount = 0.0001m;

    public decimal CurrentCount
    {
            get => Math.Round(currentCount, 2);
            set => currentCount = value;
    }

    void IncrementCount()
    {
            CurrentCount += 1.2m;
    }
}


According to the test result, we can clearly to see that even if we set limitation for the input with step="0.01", so that I think we could only add validation and format the number when set it.
void IncrementCount()
{
     currentCount = Math.Round(currentCount + 1.2m, 2);
}

We might also try @oninput="HandleInputChange" so that we can moidfy the data when the input would change.


@ oninput change will not properly format the initial value.  I did get something working using @onblur, however... the issue remained that the initial value still had 4 decimal places

Ok, I get your point and there's already a solution. Glad to see it.
